# Different layout for different module in zf2

Tags: zend-framework2

How to set different layout for different module. I have used the layout for actions i.e.

```
public function indexAction(){

     $this->layout()->setTemplate('layout/manager');
     return new ViewModel();
 }
```

It is working properly. But I want it to default for this module. So I used it in construct. But this layout is not working in the construct. Can anyone tell me how to use this layout for this module without the controller's action.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a module for having a different layout for each module.

https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpModuleLayouts

Very easy to use only follow the readme indications

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a module called Administration

**Step 1**  Add the following lines in the **Module.php** file:

*Special attention in the first function is the onBootstrap function, add the necessary lines instead of overwriting it.*

**module/Administration/Module.php**

```
public function onBootstrap($e) {
    // Register a dispatch event
    $app = $e->getParam('application');
    $app->getEventManager()->attach('dispatch', array($this, 'setLayout'));
}
public function setLayout($e) {
    $matches = $e->getRouteMatch();
    $controller = $matches->getParam('controller');
    if (false === strpos($controller, __NAMESPACE__)) {
        // not a controller from this module
        return;
    }

    // Set the layout template
    $viewModel = $e->getViewModel();
    if ($viewModel->getTemplate() === 'layout/layout') {
        $viewModel->setTemplate('layout/administration');
    }
}
```

**Step 2** Add the following lines in the **module.config.php** file:

**module/Administration/config/module.config.php**

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/administration' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'administration' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

These changes are only required in the module you want to differentiate.